# Convert String date to timestamp in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, timestamp, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection with the following data:

```
{
  "_id" : "8BDAbpoqXYpWGgy24", // String
  "date" : "2013-03-19"  // String
}
```

Is there a way to convert the date field to a timestamp value (ISODate)?

Comment: You would have to write a script, a little bit of JS that pulls out the records and resaves them as the right field

Comment: Ok, seems like this worked:
    ```db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
        doc.date=new ISODate(doc.date);
        db.collection.save(doc); 
    })```

Comment: Possibly the only thing I would add is a sort on `_id` to avoid updating documents multiple times but it is probably not a problem to you

Answer (score 3):

You can try using below [**`$toLong`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/) and [**`$dateFromString`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) aggregations

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "date": {
        "$toLong": {
          "$dateFromString": {
            "dateString": "$date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/timjZfn4mEs)